# can I make a class that combines theory and inlinedata?

Tags: c#, xunit

I've found there are a number of times I write a lot of tests where I inject similar things into them, and want to simplify the usage.  Let's use boolean as an example - but it's just representative of the problem.

At the moment, suppose there are heaps of tests of different things that can take a boolean value - you end up writing:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData( false )]
[InlineData( true )]
public async Task TestWhatever( boolean value ) ...
```

which looks sort of ridiculous.   I really want to make an attribute called TheoryBooleanAttribute so I can do

```cs
[TheoryBoolean]
public async Task TestWhatever( boolean value ) ...
```

But I can't figure out how to do it.  If I do this:

```cs
[DataDiscoverer("Xunit.Sdk.DataDiscoverer", "xunit.core")]
public class TheoryBooleanAttribute : TheoryAttribute
```

I get a message saying that I need to provide some sort of classData,InlineData etc. - which I would have thought is the point of the datadiscover attribute.  And if I do this:

```cs
[XunitTestCaseDiscoverer("Xunit.Sdk.TheoryDiscoverer", "xunit.execution.{Platform}")]
public class TheoryBooleanAttribute : DataAttribute
```

The GUI no longer sees it as a test. - which seems to be the point of the XunitTestCaseDiscoverAttribute.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `TheoryBooleanAttribute : DataAttribute` version provides the data, e.g. Boolean True/False.

Therefore you still need to put a `[Theory]` attribute on the method.

e.g.

```
[Theory]
[TheoryBoolean]
public async Task TestWhatever( boolean value ) ...
```

AFAIK there's no way to combine a `TheoryAttribute` and a `DataAttribute` into one attribute

I'm pretty sure that applying the `DataDiscoverer` attribute to a `TheoryAttribute` descendant won't work as the attribute is specifically to be applied to classes that derive from `DataAttribute`. And the same goes for an `XunitTestCaseDiscoverer` against a `DataAttribute` as it's specifically applied to `FactAttribute` derived classes.

Comment: your AFAIK is the point of the question - I am looking to find a way to combine them into one attribute.   I did figure out one way - which is to use a weaver to replumb them at compile time - but i'm still hoping to find something a little less severe